# clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Development/iPhone/Event/Event_Prefix.pch'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, clang

I've messed up my iPhone project.  I ran `svn update`, having fiddled with the repository months ago.  Many changes since, make recovering from an old point nearly impossible.

When I attempt to build the project now I get:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Event_Prefix-brpgiiwwokyynuheloumlvxlmurs/Event_Prefix.pch.pth Event_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/waterskiingmithrill/Development/iPhone/Event
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -iquote "/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/Event.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HatFair.build/Hat Fair-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/Event.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HatFair.build/Hat Fair-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/Event.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HatFair.build/Hat Fair-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/Event.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HatFair.build/Hat Fair-project-headers.hmap" -I/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/Event.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HatFair.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/Event.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HatFair.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 --serialize-diagnostics /Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Event_Prefix-brpgiiwwokyynuheloumlvxlmurs/Event_Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/waterskiingmithrill/Development/iPhone/Event/Event_Prefix.pch -o /Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Event_Prefix-brpgiiwwokyynuheloumlvxlmurs/Event_Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/waterskiingmithrill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Event-cqyicuekijryjpbuuucigvdrxrdc/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Event_Prefix-brpgiiwwokyynuheloumlvxlmurs/Event_Prefix.pch.d

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/waterskiingmithrill/Development/iPhone/Event/Event_Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

And I have no idea why `Event_Prefix.pch` is not there to be clanged. (I don't even know what clang is)  Any help, suggestions on how to debug, tips on how to fix, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clang is the compiler. Make sure you have a `Event_Prefix.pch` file in your project file.

Comment: Thanks - that's kind of exactly what it said i guess :S
If I'd thought to open the folder with that file in I'd have seen a great big red Event_Prefix.pch there show it was missing.

Comment: @DrummerB it shouldn't be added to the target, the file just needs to exist at that path

Answer (score 2):

I was having this just on a test build. Seems the test target did not update a naming change.

Comment: How did you fix that?

Comment: Hi, it's simple to fix. Just look at the error. Go to the path listed in the error. It's referencing a file that isn't there. The reason in my case was the a rename didn't carry over to the test target. So following the path to where that test target is located and making sure the name matches the name being sought solves the issue. Hope that helps. Sorry for the terse answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my search paths were not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, when renaming the project and also changing the folder names.

In Xcode you can easily set the new paths by selecting a group/folder reference, open the Utilities sidebar (Menubar: `View > Utilities > Show File Inspector`) and clicking on the small folder icon in the section "Identity and Type".

But: the paths are also set somewhere deep in the project configuration.
Select your Project, go to "Build Settings", on the left under "TARGETS" choose your App, and correct the paths of:

- Packaging > Info.plist File
- Apple LLVM 5.1 - Language > Prefix Header