# clang: error: no such file or directory: ASIAuthenticationDialog.m

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, asihttprequest

I have this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 
'/Users/usuario/Desktop/echonest-echoprint-ios-sample-b937c04/Classes/ASIHTTP/clang: 
 error: no such file or directory:'
```

I want to run the "`echoprint-ios-sample`"  project and I import the ASIHTTP files

I don´t know what is the problem  :(

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you u've deleted any h or m files, go through the project navigation(command + 1) in your xcode, there may be some reference(will be in red color) in that project navigator. U can delete it. Then there'll not be such an error. Hope this would help you.

Else, have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10619927/1424174)