# clang: error: no such file or directory when trying to run app

Tags: ios, clang

I have added flags in compile sources for janrain integration in my app.

When i m trying to run app or archiving build on that time i faced this error.

I already added that file to correct build path and its already contain within project.

Here i attached snaps of that error :

[image]

Can anyone please help me to solved this? Thanks in Advance.. :)

Comment: Please include the relevant section of code.

Comment: you are talking about which code?

Comment: sounds simple but try cleaning your project with cmd+k

Comment: Done all this things but still not working

Comment: try with alt + shift + command to cleaning build folder and then try again but still getting error.

Comment: Which flags do you added in compile sources?

Comment: i used this flag -fno-objc-arc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in your target compile sources and check its may be that you used the filename as compiler flag in ARC or you may used wrong compiler flags.

i hope its worked.

Answer (score 2):

just check your compile sources its may that you give wrong flag for ARC or your file is not available with testtareget.

Answer (score 2):

Just check your flags which u set in compile sources. Either its repeated or either its wrongly used.

Answer (score 1):

This problem raised because of i am passing this class name to set in compile sources flag instead of **-fno-objc-arc**.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your existing flags in your compile sources its may be that you used the filename as compiler flag.

Answer (score 0):

Check once NPSAuthenticatedUser+Model is existing or not in your project. Whether it is in red color or what.

If it is red color remove and re add it if needed.

Please check this answer.

[clang: error: no such file or directory: ASIAuthenticationDialog.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016016/clang-error-no-such-file-or-directory-asiauthenticationdialog-m)

Comment: its already exists and i tried with by removing and readding also but its wouldn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Build your Project and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you in the Other Linker Flags in case you use '$(inherited)', add only $(inherited) without the 2 ''

Answer (score 0):

None of the possible solutions above worked in my scenario.

For a Swift project with Objective-C file(s) included make sure they are not added to the `Build Phases -> Compile Sources` section of your project's target.

I had a Swift project where after I dragged Objective-C files into the project the implementation files were added to the `Build Phases -> Compile Sources` section. Once I removed the Objective-C implementation files from the `Compile Sources` section my project worked happily once again.

This was using Xcode version 8.3 (8E162).